# Django forms cleaned_data

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I want to create a sort_by functionality in my django app and for that I tried the following way.
**First step: forms.py**

```
class SortForm(forms.Form):
CHOICES = [
    ('latest', 'Latest Notes'),
    ('oldest', 'Oldest Notes'),
    ('alpha_descend', 'Alpahabetically (a to z)'),
    ('alpha_ascend', 'Alpahabetically (z to a)'),
]
ordering = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=CHOICES)
```

**Then views.py:**

```
def index(request):

################### Default, when form is not filled #################
notes = Note.objects.all().order_by('-last_edited')

form = SortForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SortForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        sort_by = form.cleaned_data['ordering']
        if sort_by == 'latest':
            notes = Note.objects.all().order_by('-last_edited')
        elif sort_by == 'oldest':
            notes = Note.objects.all().order_by('last_edited')
        elif sort_by == 'alpha_descend':
            notes = Note.objects.all().order_by('title')
        elif sort_by == 'alpha_ascend':
            notes = Note.objects.all().order_by('-title')
        return redirect('index')
context = {
    'notes' : notes,
    'form' : form,
}
return render(request, 'notes/index.html', context)
```

**models.py** just in case:

```
class Note(models.Model):

title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
body = models.TextField()
last_edited = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

It doesn't do anything when the **form submit**  button is pressed and refreshes the index page with the **default** lookup defined above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not redirect. Redirecting makes the client do a GET request, so `request.method == 'POST'` will be False and your ordering will not work.

```
    def index(request):
    
    ################### Default, when form is not filled #################
    notes = Note.objects.all().order_by('-last_edited')
    
    form = SortForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SortForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            sort_by = form.cleaned_data['ordering']
            if sort_by == 'latest':
                notes = Note.objects.all().order_by('-last_edited')
            elif sort_by == 'oldest':
                notes = Note.objects.all().order_by('last_edited')
            elif sort_by == 'alpha_descend':
                notes = Note.objects.all().order_by('title')
            elif sort_by == 'alpha_ascend':
                notes = Note.objects.all().order_by('-title')

            # Remove this line
            return redirect('index') 
    context = {
        'notes' : notes,
        'form' : form,
    }
    return render(request, 'notes/index.html', context)
```

Comment: Thanks bro ! Just curious, is there a better way to do what I was trying to do ?

Comment: I'd do it with a QueryString parameter like so: In your url you append ?order=title for example. And in your view you can get that parameter with: sort_by = request.GET.get('order', '-last_edited'). Note that the second argument is the default if none is supplied. There is no need to do a POST request for that.